# Two column subplot using matplotlib and seaborn

Tags: python, subplot

I have a requirement to add subplots with two column and with multiple rows. The rows will not be fixed but for one column I want to create seaborn line plot from one data set and for second column i want to create seaborn line plot for another data set.

I have tried the following but not working.

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
dataset2=tips


days = list(tips.drop_duplicates('day')['day'])
ggpec = gridspec.GridSpec(len(days ), 2)
axs = []
for i,j in zip(days,range(1,len(days)+1)):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,4),dpi=200)
    palette = sns.color_palette("magma", 2)
    chart = sns.lineplot(x="time", y="total_bill",
                      hue="sex",style='sex',
                      palette=palette, data=tips[tips['day']==i])
    chart.set_xticklabels(
        chart.get_xticklabels(), 
        rotation=90, 
        minor=True,
        verticalalignment=True,
        horizontalalignment='right',
        fontweight='light',
        fontsize='large'
    )

    plt.title("Title 1",fontsize=18, fontweight='bold')

    fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(20,5),dpi=200)
    palette = sns.color_palette("magma", 2)
    chart = sns.lineplot(x="time", y="total_bill",
                      hue="sex",style='sex',
                      palette=palette, data=dataset2[dataset2['day']==i])
    chart.set_xticklabels(
        chart.get_xticklabels(), 
        rotation=90, 
        minor=True,
        verticalalignment=True,
        horizontalalignment='right',
        fontweight='light',
        fontsize='large'
    )
    plt.title("Title 2",fontsize=18, fontweight='bold')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for creating multiple plots with 2 columns and multiple rows, you can use subplot. Where in you define the number of rows, columns and the subplot to activate at present.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.subplot(3, 2, 1)   # Define 3 rows, 2 column, Activate subplot 1. 
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 6, 5, 2, 2, 4], 'b*-', label='Plot 1')

plt.subplot(3, 2, 2)   # 3 rows, 2 column, Activate subplot 2.
# plot some data here
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 6, 5, 2, 2, 4], 'b*-', label='Plot 2')

plt.subplot(3, 2, 3)   # 3 rows, 2 column, Activate subplot 3.
# plot some data here
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 6, 5, 2, 2, 4], 'b*-', label='Plot 3')

# to Prevent subplots overlap
plt.tight_layout()  
plt.show()
```

You can build upon this concept to draw you seaborn plots as well.

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(3,2) # Divide the plot into 3 rows, 2 columns
# Draw the plot in first row second column
sns.lineplot(xData, yData, data=dataSource, ax=axes[0][1])
```